# How to say that one stuff is dedicated to something?

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to say: "this stuff is dedicated to that task"?

Comment: The answer to your actual question is yes. Your title contains an error though: you can **not** say "one stuff", since it is (generally) uncountable.

Comment: But you *can* say ***one's stuff***

Comment: How should I say instead than one stuff? I will open a question to ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes. That is a grammatically correct and meaningful sentence. Whether it accurately conveys the meaning you want to convey depends on what it is that you're trying to say.